# R converting continuous variable to categorical

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a column of continuous numeric values (NO2) which I need to convert into categorical values. Can someone explain how the following code accomplishes that:

```
cutpoints <- quantile(dataframe%NO2, seq(0,1,length=4),na.rm=TRUE)  
dataframe%newcol <- cut(dataframe%NO2, cutpoints)  
levels(dataframe%newcols) returns (0.3781,1.2] (1.2,1.42] (1.42,2.55]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use `$` instead of `%` to refer column names.

If you run the code step-by-step it will help you to understand.

`seq` creates a sequence from 0 to 1 with a length of 4.

```
seq(0,1,length=4)
#[1] 0.000 0.333 0.667 1.000
```

`quantile` breaks the vector into quantiles of data with a given probability (here `seq(0,1,length=4)`).

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(10)
cutpoints <- quantile(x, seq(0,1,length=4),na.rm=TRUE) 
#    0%  33.3%  66.7%   100% 
#0.0456 0.4566 0.7883 0.9405
```

and now these breaks are used to `cut` the data.

```
cut(x, cutpoints)
```

meaning we divide `x` into different groups where `cutpoints[1]-cutpoints[2]` is one group, `cutpoints[2]-cutpoints[3]` another group and so on.

You can also use `findInterval` instead of `cut`.